# Semantic html: Split 'article' tag / Continue previous tag

Tags: html

#### Background

Our CMS wraps pieces of content into `<article>` tags by default.
This also applies when viewing the main page for a piece of content: The main section on the page is wrapped in `<article>`.

Now we want to split that section, so that one part appears in a "banner" at the top, and another part appears below.

The html in between contains some unrelated elements, and it is controlled by another subsystem, so it would not be straightforward to wrap the entire section into a wider article tag.

(let's not go into detail about technicalities of the CMS we are using, I would like to focus on the semantic html part)

#### Example

(the real structure would be more complex, with more nesting and wrappers)

```html
<article class="banner">
  <h1>Example event</h1>
  <p>Event starts next week!</p>
</article>
<div>
 <a href="/unrelated">Unrelated navigation link, that ends up here for silly technical reasons.</a>
</div>
<article class="main">
  <!-- this article tag belongs to the same event as the above. -->
  <p>Every year we meet up and it is awesome.</p>
</article>
```

#### Question

Is there an attribute or something to indicate that the second `<article>` tag is a continuation of the first?

Or if that is not possible, what would be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Going to need a simple example of what you're talking about. No, there is no attribute to do that.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Indicate to what that it is a continuation? What needs this information?

Comment: It is a public-facing website, so the target would be any tool that consumes semantic html. Search engine crawlers, perhaps screen readers, I dunno. I think the idea of semantic html is to attempt to do the best and follow conventions and standards, without a clear expectation which tools are going to read it.

Comment: `<article>` is a container for separate content so the only way to change that is to contain the `<div>` within one element. There is no way to continue them.

Comment: Ok, a negative answer is also an answer. Even though hard to prove :) Thanks!